# How to copy data from Pixel 2 with a broken screen

Tags: backup, lock-screens, file-transfer, broken-screen, google-pixel-2

I failed to connect to my Pixel 2 with a broken screen with `adb` from MacOS in the following way:

```
$ cd Downloads/platform-tools/
$ ./adb kill-server
$ ./adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
$ ./adb shell input text 5233
adb: no devices/emulators found
```

I use a PIN to unlock my screen and USB debugging is not enabled. As soon as, I connect Pixel 2 to my Macbook the `Android File Transfer` icon only shows up but I can't connect.

Is there a way to copy files and settings from my phone to my laptop?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you set a unlock pattern/password/PIN? If yes please edit your question and add what type of lock screen protection you use. Android File Transfer is only available if your device has been unlocked, therefore you first have to unlock your device.

Comment: in addition to Robert furthermore the adb method requires usb-debugging enabled in developer options (pixel does not support MHL/HDMI you have to do that blind). to enter your pin connect PC keyboard

Comment: For starters, also make sure to check with our [broken-screen tag wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info) (especially with its recovery section).

Comment: I updated my question. How do I change to MTP after I unlocked the phone with a keyboard?

Comment: guess that's something only someone with pixel 2 can tell you